# How to write a VBA multi row coresponding cells If Statement in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

To start I am a noob. I literally just looked a VBA for the first time yesterday. So I appreciate if you dumb up your replies. lol.

A couple times a week I am given a spread sheet at work. I have to split the zip codes and move them to there perspective Store. There is about 20 zip codes and although I use the sort option, It still takes me awhile. I want to use the marco to pretty much give each zipcode a store.

Here is my issue. I am trying to look at "J1" if the zip code matches one of many I want "Bullhead" to be written in "M1"

I was able to do this, It took me several hours of trial and error to come up with the best result. I tried a lot of different things. (At the very bottom is what I came up with)

Here is the problem. I need to do this all the way down the spread Sheet. ie. if m3 = 86409 J3 = Kingman. If m4 = 86409 j4 = Kingman. So on and so on all the way to M5000,J5000.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What I want to do is simple but I could not find the answer on my own, or I could not understand it. I assume I will have to start over. And take a different approach. Not sure what though.

```
Sub MoversBirthdays()  
    Dim zipcode As Long, Store As String  
    zipcode = Range("J2").Value   
    If zipcode = "86426" Or "86427" Or "86429" Or "86430" Or "86435" Or "86436" Or "86437" Or "86438" Or "86439" Or "86440" Or "86442" Or "86446" Or "89028" Or "89029" Or "89046" Or "92304" Or "92332" Or "92363" Then Store = "Bullhead" Else: Store = "Kingman"  
    If zipcode = "" Then Store = ""  
    Range("M2").Value = Store  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub MoversBirthdays()

    Dim varZip As Variant
    Dim arrStore() As String
    Dim StoreIndex As Long

    With Range("J2", Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        ReDim arrStore(1 To .Rows.Count)
        For Each varZip In .Value
            StoreIndex = StoreIndex + 1
            Select Case varZip
                Case 86426 To 86427, 86429 To 86430, 86435 To 86440, 86442, 86446, 89028 To 89029, 89046, 92304, 92332, 92363
                    arrStore(StoreIndex) = "Bullhead"
                Case ""
                    arrStore(StoreIndex) = ""
                Case Else
                    arrStore(StoreIndex) = "Kingman"
            End Select
        Next varZip
    End With

    If StoreIndex > 0 Then Range("M2").Resize(StoreIndex).Value = Application.Transpose(arrStore)

End Sub
```

Comment: Realized I had the zip code and store columns switched (originally was looking at column M for zip codes and outputting stores to column J). I have edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: Quick question. If the cell with the zipcode is blank, it says kingman. Is there a easy way to through in a if for blanks like in mine, or would I be better off using a List of Zips for kingman as well.

Comment: I saw you did that. Its my fault in the way I explained it. I was wrong. But ty.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, you're defining `zipcode` as a `Long`, but comparing it to a String.  It should be defined as a String (or compared to Longs).

Second, you can't do an If with a list of values.  It parses, but it's interpreted as `If zipcode is 86426; Or If 86427; Or If 86429...`.  You would actually need to say `If zipcode = "xxx"` for each zip.

But since you're using Excel, you can put the list of zips on a worksheet, and just reference it for the comparison.  Assuming the list is in Column A, the following code will do what you need:

```
Sub MoversBirthdays2()
    Dim zipcode As String, Store As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("j2:j5000")
        zipcode = c.Value

        If zipcode = "" Then
            Store = ""
        Else
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a:a"), zipcode) > 0 Then
                Store = "Bullhead"
            Else
                Store = "Kingman"
            End If
        End If
        c.Offset(0, 2) = Store
    Next
End Sub
```

If you don't actually need to overwrite the value in Column M with a blank if the zip is blank, then it can be a little simpler:

```
Sub MoversBirthdays2()
    Dim zipcode As String, Store As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("j2:j5000")
        zipcode = c.Value

        If zipcode <> "" Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a:a"), zipcode) > 0 Then
                Store = "Bullhead"
            Else
                Store = "Kingman"
            End If
            c.Offset(0, 2) = Store
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ty for the response. The biggest issue I see here is that I would have to insert the zips every time I get a new worksheet. Tigers answer is mostly what I need. But I greatly appreciate your different approach.